# Add data dynamically to the charts in angular js

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I am using charts in my webapp and for that I am using angular-charts.
The html file for charts is

```
    <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data"
    chart-labels="labels">
    </canvas>
```

and the controller file for this is

```
    angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myController', function ($scope) { 

    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
    });
```

Now I just want to know how to add data dynamically into this pie chart.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the chart library you are using?

Comment: I am using Chart.js and angular-chart.js .

Comment: just push data to your data & labels arrays dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You might have a button , when you click you populate arrays your charts are bound to.

```js
$scope.onClick = function(item,label)
{
  //item and label can come from anywhere, i just add here as parameters to illustrate as example
  $scope.data.push(item);
  $scope.labels.push(label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamically data to the chart you have to push data to both the data arrays and the labels array.

> Note: Data array is not actually an array, it is an array inside an array. So data is not `[]` but rather a `[[]]`.

Code to make it work:

1. If using $scope: `$scope.data[0].push(data) and also $scope.labels.push(label)`
2. If using vm: `vm.data[0].push(data) and also vm.labels.push(label)`